# Is there a way to add a mouse event to a thread?

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qthread

I have a suspicion that something is preventing my mouse event to be called in Qt. Therefore, I think it might help to add the event to a thread. Is there any way to do that? And if so how would the syntax look?

Comment: Nothing is preventing it - please let us know exactly what you're trying to do. You're doing something wrong, but there's nothing fundamental about it. Focus on the bigger picture, not on the particular problem.

Comment: The thing is the mouse click event works when a certain part of my code is edited out. That code has no correlation with the mouse event (It basically just adds a bunch of labels to the GUI as a matrix). But thanks for the advice :)

Comment: It has all the correlation to it. You're wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt standard mouse events come to `QWidget` objects. Those must exist in the main thread, always.

So no, you can't receive the normal mouse events in other threads.

However, you should perhaps install an event filter to your main window or to your `qApp` object, so you will see all the events. Look in the docs for how to use the event filter, but in short, you need to subclass `QObject` to override the `eventFilter` method, and then create instance of this class, and install that as event filter for another object.